# How can I access the whole input from an arbitrary parser in a sequence?

Tags: parsing, haskell, dns, attoparsec, megaparsec

I'm working through a DNS message parser. I have defined the following using `megaparsec`:

## Header

```hs
data DNSHeader = DNSHeader
  { hid :: !Word16,
    hflags :: !Word16,
    hnumQuestions :: !Word16,
    hnumAnswers :: !Word16,
    hnumAuthorities :: !Word16,
    hnumAdditionals :: !Word16
  }
  deriving stock (Show)

-- >>> _debugBuilderOutput $ header2Bytes (DNSHeader 1 2 3 4 5 6)
-- "000100020003000400050006"
header2Bytes :: DNSHeader -> Builder
header2Bytes h =
  word16BE (hid h)
    <> word16BE (hflags h)
    <> word16BE (hnumQuestions h)
    <> word16BE (hnumAnswers h)
    <> word16BE (hnumAuthorities h)
    <> word16BE (hnumAdditionals h)

parseHeader :: M.Parsec Void B.ByteString DNSHeader
parseHeader =
  DNSHeader
    <$> M.word16be
    <*> M.word16be
    <*> M.word16be
    <*> M.word16be
    <*> M.word16be
    <*> M.word16be
```

## Question

```hs
data DNSQuestion = DNSQuestion
  { qname :: B.ByteString,
    qtype :: !Word16,
    qclass :: !Word16
  }
  deriving stock (Show)

parseQuestion :: M.Parsec Void B.ByteString DNSQuestion
parseQuestion =
  DNSQuestion
    <$> decodeDNSNameSimple
    <*> M.word16be
    <*> M.word16be

decodeDNSNameSimple :: M.Parsec Void B.ByteString B.ByteString
decodeDNSNameSimple = do
  len <- M.word8
  if len == 0
    then pure mempty
    else do
      name <- B.pack <$> replicateM (fromIntegral len) M.word8
      rest <- decodeDNSNameSimple
      pure $ name <> (if B.null rest then mempty else "." <> rest)
```

## Record

```hs
data DNSRecord = DNSRecord
  { rname :: B.ByteString,
    rtype :: !Word16,
    rclass :: !Word16,
    rttl :: !Word32,
    rdataLength :: !Word16,
    rdata :: B.ByteString
  }
  deriving stock (Show)

parseRecord :: M.Parsec Void B.ByteString DNSRecord
parseRecord = do
  name <- decodeDNSName
  rtype <- M.word16be
  rclass <- M.word16be
  rttl <- M.word32be
  rdataLength <- M.word16be
  rdata <- B.pack <$> replicateM (fromIntegral rdataLength) M.word8
  pure $ DNSRecord name rtype rclass rttl rdataLength rdata

decodeDNSName :: M.Parsec Void B.ByteString B.ByteString
decodeDNSName = do
  len <- M.word8
  if len == 0
    then pure mempty
    else
      if (len .&. 0b1100_0000) == 0b1100_0000
        then decodeCompressedDNSName len
        else do
          name <- B.pack <$> replicateM (fromIntegral len) M.word8
          rest <- decodeDNSName
          pure $ name <> (if B.null rest then mempty else "." <> rest)

decodeCompressedDNSName :: Word8 -> M.Parsec Void B.ByteString B.ByteString
decodeCompressedDNSName l = do
  offset' <- M.word8
  let bytes = ((fromIntegral l :: Word16) .&. 0b0011_1111) `shiftL` 8
      pointer = bytes .|. (fromIntegral offset' :: Word16)
  currentPos <- M.getOffset
  -- TODO: get to the offset defined by pointer (considering the whole input)
  -- M.setOffset (fromIntegral pointer) ???
  result <- decodeDNSName
  M.setOffset currentPos
  pure result
```

## Parsing header, question and record

```hs
parseDNSResponse :: M.Parsec Void B.ByteString (DNSHeader, DNSQuestion, DNSRecord)
parseDNSResponse = do
  header <- parseHeader
  question <- parseQuestion
  record <- parseRecord
  pure (header, question, record)
```

I'm currently stuck in the last function of the Record section, which handles possible compression (`len == 0b1100_0000`). I need to consider the whole input when moving the offset, and when I get to the third parser part of the input has already been consumed, so I reach end of input early and the parsing fails. Doing a `M.lookAhead` of the 2 first parsers would require going back and forth with the offsets. I have tried a few things without success and I'm getting a bit lost. Am I in the right direction here? Do you have a recommendation?

This is the example I'm trying to parse:

```hs
_exampleResponse :: B.ByteString
_exampleResponse = Base16.decodeLenient "e35d8180000100010000000003777777076578616d706c6503636f6d0000010001c00c000100010000508900045db8d822"
```

Header and question parsing works otherwise.

I could consider moving to other methods or parsers (`attoparsec`, etc) if they have an API more aligned with my use case, so feel free to suggest alternatives.

Comment: I would be surprised if this were possible.

Comment: Could you edit the question so it is more minimal? Maybe [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLp2qifo30hMuNgmUUhgl82DTK2JTUqK6M) could help. It is a series of video which a few of them are about parsing binary data.

Comment: @lsmor I wanted to give all the context I could to the question. Perhaps I should have linked the code from a separate service. Anyway, I came up with a solution and have added an answer. Thanks for the resource! I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you can do this with [`megaparsec`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec), as it allows [manipulating parser state](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec-9.3.0/docs/Text-Megaparsec.html#g:7) without consuming the inputs in the process. Not sure if there are other alternatives that offer this.

Calling [`getInput`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec-9.3.0/docs/src/Text.Megaparsec.html#getInput) at the very beginning of your parser gives the whole input, to which you can then apply a modified `parseRecord` so you can modify the parser input mid-parsing, do what you need, and then restore the previous state:

```hs
import Text.Megaparsec qualified as M

type DNSParser a = M.Parsec Void B.ByteString a -- For readability

parseDNSPacket :: DNSParser DNSPacket
parseDNSPacket = do
  fullInput <- M.getInput                  -- 1. Get input to this parser
  let parseRecord' = parseRecord fullInput -- 2. Apply the parser to it
  header <- parseHeader
  -- ...
  answers <- replicateM (fromIntegral $ hnumAnswers header) parseRecord'
  -- ... ...

parseRecord :: B.ByteString -> DNSParser DNSRecord
parseRecord fullInput = do
  name <- decodeDNSName fullInput
  -- ... ...

decodeDNSName :: B.ByteString -> DNSParser B.ByteString
decodeDNSName input = do
  len <- M.word8
  -- ...
      if (len .&. 0b1100_0000) == 0b1100_0000
        then decodeCompressedDNSName input len
        else do
  -- ... ...

decodeCompressedDNSName :: B.ByteString -> Word8 -> DNSParser B.ByteString
decodeCompressedDNSName input len = do
  offset' <- fromIntegral <$> M.word8
  let bytes = ((fromIntegral len :: Word16) .&. 0b0011_1111) `shiftL` 8
      pointer = fromIntegral (bytes .|. offset')
  currentPos <- M.getOffset   -- 3. Save the current input
  M.setInput input            -- 4. Set input to the argument `i`
  M.skipCount pointer M.word8 -- 5. Perform the full input parsing
  name <- decodeDNSName input
  M.setInput currentInput     -- 6. Restore the previous input
  pure name                   -- 7. Profit!
```

Now it passes simple lookup tests!